# Can Riemannian submersions produce all homotopy classes?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory

What is an example of two Riemannian manifolds $(M,N)$ which admits at least one Riemannian submersion $f:M\to N$ but there exist a continuous map $g:M\to N$ with the same induced maps $f^*=g^*$ on de Rham cohomologies  but $g$ is homotopic to no Riemannian submersion?

Comment: $M = S^3\cong SU(2),N = S^2\cong SU(2)/U(1)$ equipped with left-invariant metrics, $f:M\to N$ the quotient map/Hopf fibration and $g$ constant should work, as any Riemannian fibration $M\to N$ must have fiber $S^1$, so that the homotopy type of the total space is determined by the Euler class $e\in\mathbb Z$ of this bundle, and the only cases where it is homotopy equivalent to $S^3$ are $e=\pm 1$, in which case the map down to $S^2$ is the Hopf fibration or its negative, in particular not homotopic to zero.

Comment: You don't even need the precise analysis of the fiber: Any fibration homotopic to the constant map will have fiber $S^3 \times \Omega S^2$, not a manifold. This directly shows that the constant map can't be homotopic to a submersion. (Riemannian is completely irrelevant)

Comment: @BertramArnold Thank you for your attention to my question. It is a little strange that the main motivation for my question was the following: when  a  vector bundle $E\to S^2$ has a clutching function $\alpha: S^1 \to  GL(n.\mathbb{R})$ such that $\alpha$ determines a geodesic!!!When A vector bundle $E\to S^n$has a clutching function $\beta:S^{n-1}\to GL(n.\mathbb{R})$ has a "nice geometric structure"? and what would be the effect of this geometric structure on the total space of the bundle?Since homotopy class of the clutching function affect on the structure of the bundle so I lead to this

Comment: to this question. Again I admit that my question is far from the initial motivation.

Comment: @AchimKrause  Thank you  for your attention to my question. Please  read my previous comment.